# Many files were changed to root as owner by GCP. Can't delete them!

Tags: root, gcp

Many files had their ownership changed to root in GCP and now I can't remove them. How do I change it back? GCP help is hard to come by.
Thanks,
-Marcos

Comment: If someone accidentially did a `chown root:root /*`, you're probably better off recreating the server.

Comment: I didn't do it. Somehow the file permissions and dates even changed.

Comment: Are they system files, or your files?

Comment: They are files in /usr/lib/cgi-bin and also my own files.

Comment: Can you open a root shell or do you have sudoer rights on the machine? If so, then you can just delete them. There has to be something in the config or on the machine that has changed the owner. It doesn't just happen.